# Learning Hilchos Chalev and Seder Kodshim as segulah for Refuah

Tags: sources-mekorot, health-safety-shmira, segulah

A friend of mine was recently in Eretz Yisrael. When he was here he visited many Gedolim to get brachas for his son who was born with a number of birth defects. He was by R' Chaim Kanevsky to a get a bracha and asked for eitzas in the matter. Among the things R' Chaim told him to do is learn a mesecta from Seder Kodshim (he said Zevachim b'frat) and to learn Hilchos Chalev (Yoreh De'ah Siman 64.)

If it would have been said by anyone else (A Chassidishe Rebbe, a Makubel, etc.) I wouldn't have been so interested to know why davka these 2 things. But since R' Chaim said it it's a bit more interesting. Perhaps there is some "makor" to this that the limud of these 2 things is a segulah for refuah?

Comment: Intersting, since he usually recommends Mas. Kinim with a specific Perush.

Comment: @DannySchoemann maybe this is a "shoresh neshamah" thing...But I don't know if I'd go that far with R' Chaim.

Comment: I'm not sure about as being a _Segulah_ for _Refu'ah_, but _Sefer Chasidim_ ( in _Siman_ 588, also in _Siman_ 1) says that one who learns a Torah subject that is a "_Met Mitzvah_", i.e. that others don't study( he gives _Seder Kodashim_ as an example), is greatly rewarded. Maybe R. Chaim was suggesting learning those subjects to increase your friends merit( for them being today's "_Met Mitzvah_"), which could pay back in answering prayers for _Refu'ah_.

Comment: @TamirEvan Is Siman 588 right?

Comment: @Yehoshua Yes, _Siman_ 588(תקפח), but it turns out that would be in the editions based on the Berlin edition( in turn based on the Parma manuscript), like the one [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=2193&pgnum=349). In those based on the Bologna edition, it( at least, the relevant part) is in _Siman_ 261(רסא), like [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14561&pgnum=80).

Comment: @TamirEvan I'm using the one from Mossad HaRav Kook it's Siman 261. Thanks.